# What is the best way to limit a person submitting to a form more than X amount of times whilst using Email as the unique identifier?

Tags: javascript, validation, dictionary, increment

I have programmed a reservation creation form for my users. The user's email address is the unique and unchanging identifier on the form (it is passed through SSO). My problem is I want to limit the number of times a user can make a reservation to X.

I am limited to JavaScript as I am developing inside an off the shelf solution code editor. I have looked at introducing a dictionary of all the emails that are going to access the system and then incrementing until reaching X number. However JavaScript is a pretty new language to me and I was hoping somebody could provide some guidance?

ID of the field is "email"

Here is some code for the form if you need it:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
  Email:<br>
  <input type="text" name="emailinput" id="email">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't verify that *safely* using client-side Javascript. You could use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to store the amount of times a user has booked a reservation.

This really depends in your use case. If you just want to play around with Javascript and experiment with validation, just do

```js
const onClickGuard = (event) => {
  const maxReservations = 5;
  const userReservationCount = localStorage.getItem('reservationCount') || 0;
  if(userReservationCount >= maxReservations) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.error(`You already booked ${maxReservations} tiemes!`)
  }
  else {
   localStorage.setItem('reservationCount', userReservationCount+1);
  }
}
```

And in your HTML do:

```html
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="onClickGuard">
```

But if this is some real (non-training) project that requires real web security, you'll need to use a database and store the number of reservations in it for each user. Which means plain javascript on the client-side is not enough. With the above solution someone could just delete the localStorage in their browser and book as many times as they want

Comment: Thanks very much Artur! I suspected that may be the case, thank you for your guidance